# How is filetype tex and plaintex set in vanilla Vim?

Tags: filetype, filetype-tex

I noticed that when I create a `.tex` from within Vim itself, in a later session that file is detected as `plaintex`, while already existing files are detected with the `tex` filetype (***note***: both of them have the `.tex` file extension).

I noticed it, since the syntax highlighting was different between the two.

I then created `after\ftplugin\plaintex.vim` in which I added

```
set filetype=tex
```

which does change the `filetype`, but it does not apply the relative syntax highlighting. I guess because this is done after the buffer is already loaded and processed.

I then tried with `ftdetect/plaintex.vim` with

```
setfiletype tex
set filetype=tex
```

It didn't work either.

I think the last option would be to work with either `filetype.vim` or `script.vim` to set filetype before built-in detection.

How can I make Vim assign the `"tex"` filetype when creating `.tex` files?

<sub>I've been trying to solve this myself, without success.</sub>

Comment: Do you have some kind of tex/latex package installed or is it vanilla Vim?

Comment: I only have `Texlab` LSP installed (using Neovim). So, I guess for the matter, it is like vanilla vim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `filetype` of a `.tex` file is determined by the content of the file.

In particular, if the first lines contains:

- `%&plaintex` then it will be considered `plaintex`,
- `%&tex` then it will be considered `tex`

If no `%&format` is found:

The `filetype` is by default set to:

- `plaintex` if `g:tex_flavor` is set to `plain` or not defined
- `context` if `g:tex_flavor` is set to `context`
- `tex` otherwise

But the logic will further explore the first 1000 lines of the file for LaTeX or ConTeX constructions and set the `filetype` accordingly.

The list of LaTeX constructions in Vim 9.0 seems to be:

- `\documentclass`
- `\usepackage`
- `\begin{`
- `\newcommnand`
- `\renewcommand`

The list of ConTeX constructions in Vim 9.0 seems to be:

- `\start`
- `\setup`
- `\usemodule`
- `\enablemode`
- `\setvariables`
- `\useenconding`
- `\usesymbol`
- `\stelle`
- `\verwende`
- `\stel`
- `\gebruik`
- `\usa`
- `\imposta`
- `\regle`
- `\utilisemodule`

To have it set to `tex` instead of `plaintex` I see three solutions:

1. Start the file with `%&tex`
2. Set the `g:tex_flavor` to `tex`
3. Make sure the content of the files contains `\documentclass` (or any LaTeX constructions)

To have it set to `plaintex` instead of `tex` I see two solutions:

1. Start the files with `%&plaintex`
2. Make sure the content of the file does not contain LaTeX constructions or ConTeX constructions.

More information with `:help ft-tex-plugin`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me try the `g:tex_flavor` approach, if it works. But then, yet I'd love to understand the reasons of the difference in detection, for two similar file (i.e. both of them not including anyu `\documentclass`), just created *differently*.

Comment: I'm sorry Vivian, but it looks like this does not work as hoped. 
I double checked to be sure, but now setting `"g:tex_flavor = "plain"` does not prevent those same files to be still detected as "tex" filetype.. It seems to be working with `tex_flavor = "latex"` though... Anyway, I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: If you set `g:tex_flavor` to `'plain'` but the content of the files contains `\documentclass` or LaTeX construction then Vim will consider it as LaTeX and will set the `filetype` as `tex`.

Comment: I have precised the answer. Let me know if it match your experience :-)

Comment: A BIG thank you for having clarified this!! :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-) I hope it will also help others because the doc is quite vague about this ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149819/discussion-between-mem-and-vivian-de-smedt).